# Spring Tomcat C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager creates a memory leak

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat

My app is written in Spring/Hibernate and runs on Tomcat 7.  Whenever I stop tomcat I get the log below.  I have applied some suggestions like deregister the MySQL driver inside a Listener registered in web.xml but it does not work. I still get the error below.

```
Aug 11, 2015 2:20:00 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/myapp] appears to have started a thread named [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2wpukr9b7lu7n8gy0sz2|26476002]-AdminTaskTimer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Aug 11, 2015 2:20:00 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/myapp] appears to have started a thread named [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2wpukr9b7lu7n8gy0sz2|26476002]-HelperThread-#0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Aug 11, 2015 2:20:00 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/myapp] appears to have started a thread named [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2wpukr9b7lu7n8gy0sz2|26476002]-HelperThread-#1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Aug 11, 2015 2:20:00 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/myapp] appears to have started a thread named [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2wpukr9b7lu7n8gy0sz2|26476002]-HelperThread-#2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Aug 11, 2015 2:20:00 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/myapp] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Aug 11, 2015 2:20:00 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/myapp] appears to have started a thread named [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2wpukr9b7lu7n8gy0sz2|1e7f9929]-AdminTaskTimer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Aug 11, 2015 2:20:00 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/myapp] appears to have started a thread named [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2wpukr9b7lu7n8gy0sz2|1e7f9929]-HelperThread-#0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Aug 11, 2015 2:20:00 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/myapp] appears to have started a thread named [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2wpukr9b7lu7n8gy0sz2|1e7f9929]-HelperThread-#1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Aug 11, 2015 2:20:00 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/myapp] appears to have started a thread named [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2wpukr9b7lu7n8gy0sz2|1e7f9929]-HelperThread-#2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Aug 11, 2015 2:20:00 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
```

Comment: The memory leak is probably due to some not released resources. Specifically, you probable have not closed some connections, which create this problem. You can also check the following response :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063414/hibernate4-c3p0-derby-memory-leak-on-tomcat-stop-or-web-application-reload/16078582#16078582

Comment: Thank you the code snippet helped me remove the error.  I put the code inside listener and it worked!